# I want my character to move hexagonally but don't know how to re-write the code so it works on a hexagonal tilemap

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var speed: int = 35

func handleInput():
    var moveDirection = Input.get_vector( "ui_left", "ui_right", "ui_up", "ui_down",)
    velocity = moveDirection*speed
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    handleInput()
    move_and_slide()
```

I tried looking online how to implement hexagonal movement but nothing is clear.

Comment: I would like to help but need more details. Could you give an example of a game that moves like that? If not can you answer these for me:
1. Do you want them to move by tiles, like in Pokemon Red
2. Do you want them to only move diagonal or also vertical and horizontal
3. And still an example from another game. Would really help.